# Trying to workspace setup in Eclips for existing maven project build error occurs

Tags: eclipse, groovy, maven-plugin, eclipse-jdt, build-error

I am trying to setup workspace in eclipse which required maven and groovy plugins. While trying to build project i am getting below error, could anyone can please help me to understand what is going wrong and how can we resolved it.

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project
'management'.
org/codehaus/jdt/groovy/integration/LanguageSupportFactory

[Click to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmYKR.png)

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. [Edit] your question to show us the extra detail.